# xUnit's Theory on Team City have different output between the MSBuild runner and console

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, xunit

I use xUnit on Team City to execute my tests.

I have switched from the MSBuild runner to the console in order to have the code coverage enabled.

But between the two results I have "lost" some tests: 
for the MSBuild runner, each InlineData of each Theory are displayed, like that:

```
OK  SiteContextGeneratorTests.site_context_pages_have_date_in_bag(fileName: "C:\TestSite\2014-01-01-ByFilename.md", useDefault: False) (Pretzel.Tests.dll:Pretzel.Tests.Templating.Context)
OK  SiteContextGeneratorTests.site_context_pages_have_date_in_bag(fileName: "C:\TestSite\UsingDefault.md", useDefault: True) (Pretzel.Tests.dll:Pretzel.Tests.Templating.Context)
```

for the console (xunit.console.clr4.exe) the output for the same test is:

```
OK (2 runs)     SiteContextGeneratorTests. site_context_pages_have_date_in_bag (Pretzel.Tests.dll:Pretzel.Tests.Templating.Context)
```

Is there a way to have the same output as the MSBuild runner with the console?